# Add obsoletes/conflicts fields to debuginfo RPM package?

Tags: packaging, rpm, specifications

Going through a package name change, so all my new packages (eg newlib, newlib-devel, etc) obsolete and conflict with the old packages (eg oldlib, oldlib-devel).

The -debuginfo package however is automatically created, is there a way to add obsoletes and conflicts fields to the package without disabling its automatic creation (%define debuginfo %{nil}) and creating the debuginfo package "by hand"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved your problem but for me it was enough to add  **-debuginfo* package to *Obsoletes* field of my RPM spec. Otherwise I had conflicts when trying to update the old package.

Example:

```
Obsoletes: oldlib oldlib-debuginfo
```

Cheers,
Tomasz